# Using Javascript To Toggle CSS - Disabling The Scroll Behind the Hamburger Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is both the HTML and CSS I'm using to create a website. I have no previous
experience with Javascript, so I'm unfamiliar with how to use it but would like to
be able to use Javascript to toggle some CSS so that the background doesn't scroll
when my hamburger menu is open. I'm stuck, but if anyone has any advice to give me
it'd be much appreciated.

Please ignore the Javascript above as this applies to the search bar I intend to use.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en; jp;">

<body style="background-color: white;">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <div class="page-wrap">

    <div class="cp_cont">
      <input id="cp_toggle03" type="checkbox" />
      <div class="cp_mobilebar">
        <label for="cp_toggle03" class="cp_menuicon">
                <span></span>
                </label>
      </div>
      <label id="h-menu_black" class="cp_toggle03" for="cp_menuicon"></label>
      <div id="body" class="noscroll"></div>

      <header class="cp_offcm03">

        <nav>
          <ul style="text-align: center; margin-left: 210px; overflow: hidden;">

            <li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">ホーム</a></li>
            <li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">ブログ</a></li>
            <li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">小泉ついて</a></li>
            <li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">参考文献</a></li>


            <div class="searchbar">

              <form id="frmSearch" class="search2" method="get" action="default.html" style=" padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 20px; text-align: right; position: inline;" />
              <input class="search2" id="txtSearch" type="text" name="serach_bar" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" style="center: 396px; top: 185px; width: 180px; height: 26px;" />
              <input class="search1" type="submit" name="submition" value="検索" style=" padding-  
            bottom:20px; left: 0px; top: 153px; height: 25px; width: 32px;" />
              <input class="search2" type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="default.html" />


              <script type="text/javascript">
                document.getElementById('frmSearch').onsubmit = function() {
                  window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:yoursitename.com ' + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
                  return false;
                }
              </script>

            </div>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>


      <div class="setsumei">

        <br>
        <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 40px;">東京都</h1>
        <br>
        <p style="text-align: justify; font-size: 16px;">

          #

        </p>

      </div>

      <br>
      <div class="image">

        <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="85%"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="85%"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="85%"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="85%"></a>



      </div>
    </div>

    <br><br>
    <footer class="site-footer" style="font-size: 12px;"> | <a href="#">English</a></footer>

  </div>

  <style>
      .searchbar {
      float: right;
    }
    
    .image {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .setsumei {
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
    
    .footer {
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      text-align: center;
      border-top: 1px solid black;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .page-wrap {
      min-height: 100%;
      /* equal to footer height */
      margin-bottom: -40px;
    }
    
    .page-wrap:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
    }
    
    .site-footer,
    .page-wrap:after {
      /* .push must be the same height as footer */
      height: 40px;
    }
    
    .site-footer {
      text-align: center;
      border-top: 1px solid black;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      padding-left: 0;
      `enter code here` margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    ol,
    ul {
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .cp_cont {
      height: auto;
    }
    /* menu */
    
    .cp_offcm03 {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 5000;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      overflow: auto;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      padding-top: 0;
      -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
      transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      background-color: white;
    }
    
    .cp_offcm03 nav,
    .cp_offcm03 ul {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .cp_offcm03 li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: -6px;
    }
    
    .cp_offcm03 a {
      display: block;
      padding: 15px 45px;
      margin-bottom: -5px;
      -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
      transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
    }
    
    .cp_offcm03 a:hover {
      background-color: lightgray;
    }
    /* menu toggle */
    
    #cp_toggle03 {
      display: none;
    }
    
    #cp_toggle03:checked~.cp_offcm03 {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    
    #cp_toggle03:checked~.cp_container {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    
    .cp_mobilebar {
      display: none;
    }
    /* content */
    
    .cp_container {
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      padding: 35px auto;
      -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
      transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    }
    
    .cp_content {
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 20px;
      height: 65vh;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 1050px)and (min-width: 480px) {
      /* menu */
      .cp_offcm03 {
        position: fixed;
        left: -250px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        width: 250px;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 40px;
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
        z-index: 1000;
      }
      .cp_offcm03 nav {
        background: white;
        border-right: 0.5px solid lightgray;
        margin-left: -210px;
      }
      .cp_offcm03 li {
        display: block;
        margin-right: 0;
      }
      .cp_offcm03 a {
        padding: 20px;
      }
      /* menu toggle */
      .cp_mobilebar {
        display: block;
        z-index: 2000;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0 25px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: white;
        border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;
      }
      .cp_menuicon {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 25px;
        height: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
        transition: transform .3s ease-in;
      }
      .cp_menuicon>span {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 55%;
        margin-top: -0.3em;
        width: 100%;
        height: 0.2em;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: black;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease;
        transition: transform .3s ease;
      }
      .cp_menuicon>span:before,
      .cp_menuicon>span:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: black;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
        transition: transform .3s ease-in;
      }
      .cp_menuicon>span:before {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.6em);
        transform: translateY(-0.6em);
      }
      .cp_menuicon>span:after {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0.6em);
        transform: translateY(0.6em);
      }
      #cp_toggle03:checked+.cp_mobilebar .cp_menuicon {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
      }
      #cp_toggle03:checked+.cp_mobilebar span:before,
      #cp_toggle03:checked+.cp_mobilebar span:after {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
      }
      #cp_toggle03:checked~.cp_offcm03 {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
        transform: translateX(100%);
      }
      #cp_toggle03:checked~.cp_container {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
        transform: translateX(250px);
      }
      input:checked~#h-menu_black {
        display: block;
        /*カバーを表示*/
        opacity: .6;
      }
      #h-menu_black {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 999;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: black;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: .7s ease-in-out;
      }
      /* content */
      .cp_container {
        top: 60px;
        height: 92vh;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .noscroll {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
      }
  </style>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an onchange event on the input you used to toggle the hamburger menu.

```
document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').onchange = function() {
  if (document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').checked) {
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  } else {
    document.body.style.overflow = "";
  }
}
```

```js
document.getElementById('frmSearch').onsubmit = function() {
  window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:yoursitename.com ' + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
  return false;
}

document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').onchange = function() {
  if (document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').checked) {
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  } else {
    document.body.style.overflow = "";
  }
}
```

```css
  .searchbar {
  float: right;
}

.image {
  text-align: center;
}

.setsumei {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -40px;
}

.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.site-footer,
.page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 40px;
}

.site-footer {
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  padding-left: 0;
  `enter code here` margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.cp_cont {
  height: auto;
}


/* menu */

.cp_offcm03 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

.cp_offcm03 nav,
.cp_offcm03 ul {
  height: 100%;
}

.cp_offcm03 li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -6px;
}

.cp_offcm03 a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 45px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
  transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
}

.cp_offcm03 a:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}


/* menu toggle */

#cp_toggle03 {
  display: none;
}

#cp_toggle03:checked~.cp_offcm03 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

#cp_toggle03:checked~.cp_container {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.cp_mobilebar {
  display: none;
}


/* content */

.cp_container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  padding: 35px auto;
  -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
  transition: transform .3s ease-in;
}

.cp_content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 65vh;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 1050px)and (min-width: 480px) {
  /* menu */
  .cp_offcm03 {
    position: fixed;
    left: -250px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 40px;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1000;
  }
  .cp_offcm03 nav {
    background: white;
    border-right: 0.5px solid lightgray;
    margin-left: -210px;
  }
  .cp_offcm03 li {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .cp_offcm03 a {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  /* menu toggle */
  .cp_mobilebar {
    display: block;
    z-index: 2000;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 25px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;
  }
  .cp_menuicon {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 25px;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    transition: transform .3s ease-in;
  }
  .cp_menuicon>span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    margin-top: -0.3em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.2em;
    border-radius: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease;
    transition: transform .3s ease;
  }
  .cp_menuicon>span:before,
  .cp_menuicon>span:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    transition: transform .3s ease-in;
  }
  .cp_menuicon>span:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.6em);
    transform: translateY(-0.6em);
  }
  .cp_menuicon>span:after {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0.6em);
    transform: translateY(0.6em);
  }
  #cp_toggle03:checked+.cp_mobilebar .cp_menuicon {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  #cp_toggle03:checked+.cp_mobilebar span:before,
  #cp_toggle03:checked+.cp_mobilebar span:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  #cp_toggle03:checked~.cp_offcm03 {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  #cp_toggle03:checked~.cp_container {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
    transform: translateX(250px);
  }
  input:checked~#h-menu_black {
    display: block;
    /*カバーを表示*/
    opacity: .6;
  }
  #h-menu_black {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .7s ease-in-out;
  }
  /* content */
  .cp_container {
    top: 60px;
    height: 92vh;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .noscroll {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
  }
```

```html
<body style="background-color: white;">

  <div class="page-wrap">

    <div class="cp_cont">
      <input id="cp_toggle03" type="checkbox" />
      <div class="cp_mobilebar">
        <label for="cp_toggle03" class="cp_menuicon">
            <span></span>
            </label>
      </div>
      <label id="h-menu_black" class="cp_toggle03" for="cp_menuicon"></label>
      <div id="body" class="noscroll"></div>

      <header class="cp_offcm03">

        <nav>
          <ul style="text-align: center; margin-left: 210px; overflow: hidden;">

            <li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">ホーム</a></li>
            <li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">ブログ</a></li>
            <li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">小泉ついて</a></li>
            <li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">参考文献</a></li>


            <div class="searchbar">

              <form id="frmSearch" class="search2" method="get" action="default.html" style=" padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 20px; text-align: right; position: inline;" />
              <input class="search2" id="txtSearch" type="text" name="serach_bar" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" style="center: 396px; top: 185px; width: 180px; height: 26px;" />
              <input class="search1" type="submit" name="submition" value="検索" style=" padding-  
        bottom:20px; left: 0px; top: 153px; height: 25px; width: 32px;" />
              <input class="search2" type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="default.html" />


            </div>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>


      <div class="setsumei">

        <br>
        <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 40px;">東京都</h1>
        <br>
        <p style="text-align: justify; font-size: 16px;">

          #

        </p>

      </div>

      <br>
      <div class="image">

        <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="85%"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="85%"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="85%"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="85%"></a>



      </div>
    </div>

    <br><br>
    <footer class="site-footer" style="font-size: 12px;"> | <a href="#">English</a></footer>

  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, this is exactly what I was looking to do!
You're a really good programmer!

Comment: Glad I could help :)